# como elegir una letra de un archivo de texto y usarlo como variable

Tags: java, archivo, variables

tengo un código donde almaceno la información obtenida de un fichero a un área de texto en java, pero no se como hacer para obtener la información de cada palabra aparte y usarlas como variables.
Este es el código:

```java
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); //permite mostrar fácilmente una ventana para la selección de un fichero 

fc.showOpenDialog(null);
File archivo = fc.getSelectedFile();//permite seleccionar el archivo 
try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivo);
    /*espacio de memoria*/BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String texto ="";
    String linea = "";
    String tex ="";
    int cont =1;
    while(((linea = br.readLine())!= null)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,linea);
        texto+= linea+"\n";   
    } 
             
            
            
    txaArchivo.setText(" ");
    txaArchivo.setText(texto);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo leido correctamente");
    // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,st.countTokens());
        
 }
 catch (Exception e){
            
 }
```

Comment: Si quieres separa al linea  en palabras puedes usar : `String[]   palabras = linea.split(" ");`. No sé si  eso es lo que quieres.

Comment: gracias juan carlos, realmente necesito usar los numeros ingresados a un txt y usarlos como variables para grafos y en cada linea ira una funcion diferente

Comment: Entonces, puedes usar un `Map<String,Object>` dónde la key es el nombre de la letra y el Object su valor . De esta forma similar una variable. A medida que lees el archivo vas agregando las letras a tu `Map`:  miVars.put(letra,algún valor). Luego lo utilizas : MiVars[letra]. (No recuerdo si es put o Add).